# Arduino (C) - "expected primary-expression before ')'

Tags: c, while-loop, arduino

I've got a function that works in my test document, but when transfered to my finished project I get the error "expected ´)' before ';' token".

I've included first the program in its functional test state, as well as the code of the non-functional code, I know the second one is still messy but has been functional so far, and I'm hoping to figure out why the while function causes errors. I am also sorry that the code is not in full english but rather danish, I hope this does not make it completely impossible.

Error messages from compiler:

Skarmmedudtest_V_1_1.ino: In function 'float tagTemp_NTC() ':
Skarmmedudtest_V_1_1:142: error: expected: ´)' before ';' token
Skarmmedudtest_V_1_1:142: error: expected: primary-expression before ')' token
Skarmmedudtest_V_1_1:142: error: expected: ´;' before ')' token
Skarmmedudtest_V_1_1:806: error: expected: ´}' at end of input

Functional code:

```
    #define STR 100
float ar[STR];
float x;
int i;
int sum;
float mindstLuft;
float temp;

//DENNNE VIRKER OG MÅLER MED EN NØJAGTIGHED PÅ 0.5 GRADER
void TagTemp(){ 
float hej = analogRead(A0);
temp = (float)0.10988796957380947*(float)hej-(float)31.34142857142854334;
 }


float tagTemp_NTC()
{
  int i=0;
  mindstLuft=1000; //sikre at den første måling -altid- er anderledes//

  while (i<STR)
  {
  float hej = analogRead(A0);
  temp = (float)0.10988796957380947*(float)hej-(float)31.34142857142854334;
  delay(1);
  if(temp<mindstLuft)
  {mindstLuft=temp;}
  return mindstLuft; 
  i++;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop()
{ 
  tagTemp_NTC();
  Serial.print("Smallest measurement is;");
  Serial.println(mindstLuft);  



//}
delay(1000);
}
```

Disfunctional code;

```
 #include <Tone.h>
#include <i2cmaster.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_PCD8544.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <Thermistor.h>
#include "pitches.h"
Thermistor temp(0);

// Software SPI (slower updates, more flexible pin options):
// pin 7 - Serial clock out (SCLK)
// pin 6 - Serial data out (DIN)
// pin 5 - Data/Command select (D/C)
// pin 4 - LCD chip select (CS)
// pin 3 - LCD reset (RST)
Adafruit_PCD8544 display = Adafruit_PCD8544(7, 6, 5, 4, 3);

// Hardware SPI (faster, but must use certain hardware pins):
// SCK is LCD serial clock (SCLK) - this is pin 13 on Arduino Uno
// MOSI is LCD DIN - this is pin 11 on an Arduino Uno
// pin 5 - Data/Command select (D/C)
// pin 4 - LCD chip select (CS)
// pin 3 - LCD reset (RST)
// Adafruit_PCD8544 display = Adafruit_PCD8544(5, 4, 3);
// Note with hardware SPI MISO and SS pins aren't used but will still be read
// and written to during SPI transfer.  Be careful sharing these pins!

//////////////////GLOBALE DATAVÆRDIER/////////////////////
#define STR 100;
#define reed 52//pin connected to read switch
unsigned long start, finished, elapsed, midt;
int reedVal = 0;
int counter = 1;
int array[1];
int countLyd = 0;
float tid;
float distance;
int buttonState=1;
int count =0;
float mindstLuft;
//////////////////GLOBALE DATAVÆRDIER/////////////////////









/////////////////////////////////////     UR      ///////////////////////////////////////

void ur()
{

  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(42,0);
  display.print(hour());
  taltilur(minute());
  taltilur(second());
  display.println();
}

void taltilur(int digits)
{
  display.print(":");
  if(digits < 10)
    display.print('0');
  display.print(digits);
}

int sensorValueNTC = analogRead(A0);
int sensorValueIFR = analogRead(A1);
int sensorValueFart = analogRead(A2);
int sensorValueDistance = analogRead(A3);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int temperatureIR;

void vejTemp()
{
  //////////////////////////////////KODE TIL IR SENSOR///////////////////////////////////
  int dev = 0x5A<<1;
  int data_low = 0;
  int data_high = 0;
  int pec = 0;

  i2c_start_wait(dev+I2C_WRITE);
  i2c_write(0x07);

  // read
  i2c_rep_start(dev+I2C_READ);
  data_low = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
  data_high = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
  pec = i2c_readNak();
  i2c_stop();

  //This converts high and low bytes together and processes temperature, MSB is a error bit and is ignored for temps
  double tempFactor = 0.02; // 0.02 degrees per LSB (measurement resolution of the MLX90614)
  double tempData = 0x0000; // zero out the data
  int frac; // data past the decimal point

  // This masks off the error bit of the high byte, then moves it left 8 bits and adds the low byte.
  tempData = (double)(((data_high & 0x007F) << 8) + data_low);
  tempData = (tempData * tempFactor)-0.01;

  float celcius = tempData - 273.15;
  float fahrenheit = (celcius*1.8) + 32;

  display.setTextSize(1.5);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(0,25);
  display.print("Vej temp:");
  display.setTextSize(1.5);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(60,25);
  display.print(celcius,1); // - temp fra infrarød
  //display.print("10*");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////











///////////////////////////////   NTC TEMP    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
float tagTemp_NTC()
{
  int i=0;
  mindstLuft=1000; //sikre at den første måling -altid- er anderledes//

  while (i<STR)
    {
    float hej = analogRead(A0);
    temp = (float)0.10988796957380947*(float)hej-(float)31.34142857142854334;
    delay(1);
    if(temp<mindstLuft)
    {mindstLuft=temp;}
    return mindstLuft; 
    i++;
    }
}

void luftTemp()
{

  display.setTextSize(1.5);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(0,35);
  display.print("Luft temp:");
  display.setTextSize(1.5);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(60,35);
  display.print(mindst_luft, 1);

  //display.print("10*");
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////











//////////////////////////////////////     DISTANCE    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
void distance2()
{


  float radius = 0.35; //meter. Dette skal brugeren selv skrive ind fra skaermen.
  float hjulomkreds = 3.14 * (radius*2);


  reedVal = digitalRead(reed);//get val of A0



  if(reedVal == 1 && counter == 1)
  {
    counter = 0;

    start = millis();

  }
  if(reedVal == 0 && counter == 0)
  {

    counter = 2;
  }


  if(reedVal == 1 && counter == 2)
  {
    finished = millis();
    elapsed = (finished - start);
    array[1] = elapsed;
    tid = array[1];


    counter = 0;
    start = millis();
    distance = distance + hjulomkreds;
  }
  delay(200);


  float hastighed =   ((hjulomkreds/tid)*3600);


  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(1,0);
  display.print(distance); // - distance fra sensor
  //display.print("10km");
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////









////////////////////////////////////   FART   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void fart()
{

  float radius = 0.35; //meter. Dette skal brugeren selv skrive ind fra skaermen.
  float hjulomkreds = 2 * 3.14 * radius*radius;


  reedVal = digitalRead(reed);//get val of A0



  if(reedVal == 1 && counter == 1)
  {
    counter = 0;

    start = millis();

  }
  if(reedVal == 0 && counter == 0)
  {

    counter = 2;
  }


  if(reedVal == 1 && counter == 2)
  {
    finished = millis();
    elapsed = (finished - start);
    array[1] = elapsed;
    tid = array[1];


    counter = 0;
    start = millis();
    distance = distance + 0.35;
  }
  delay(200);

  //float hastighed = ((hjulomkreds * 3600)/tid); //  Km/t
  float hastighed =   ((hjulomkreds/tid)*3600);  


  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(0,10);
  display.print("Fart:");
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(30,10);
  display.print(hastighed, 1);
  display.setCursor(60,10);
  display.print("km/t");

}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////











/////////////////////////////////////    LYS DIODER     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
void lysG()
{
  digitalWrite(22, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(24, LOW);
  digitalWrite(26, LOW);
}

void lysR()
{
  digitalWrite(22, LOW);
  digitalWrite(26, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(24, LOW);
}

void lysY()
{
  digitalWrite(22, LOW);
  digitalWrite(26, LOW);
  digitalWrite(24, HIGH);
}

void slukLysGreen()
{
  digitalWrite(22, LOW);
}

void slukLysYellow()
{
  digitalWrite(24, LOW);
}

void slukLysRed()
{
  digitalWrite(26, LOW);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////












///////////FUNKTIONER TIL 1 PER SKÆRM//////////////
void ur1()
{
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setCursor(0,20);
  display.print(hour());
  taltilur(minute());
  taltilur(second());
  display.println();
  display.display();
}


void vejTemp1()
{
  display.clearDisplay();
  //////////////////////////////////KODE TIL IR SENSOR///////////////////////////////////
  int dev = 0x5A<<1;
  int data_low = 0;
  int data_high = 0;
  int pec = 0;

  i2c_start_wait(dev+I2C_WRITE);
  i2c_write(0x07);

  // read
  i2c_rep_start(dev+I2C_READ);
  data_low = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
  data_high = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
  pec = i2c_readNak();
  i2c_stop();

  //This converts high and low bytes together and processes temperature, MSB is a error bit and is ignored for temps
  double tempFactor = 0.02; // 0.02 degrees per LSB (measurement resolution of the MLX90614)
  double tempData = 0x0000; // zero out the data
  int frac; // data past the decimal point

  // This masks off the error bit of the high byte, then moves it left 8 bits and adds the low byte.
  tempData = (double)(((data_high & 0x007F) << 8) + data_low);
  tempData = (tempData * tempFactor)-0.01;

  float celcius = tempData - 273.15;
  float fahrenheit = (celcius*1.8) + 32;

  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(15,5);
  display.print("Vej temp:");
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(15,25);
  display.print(celcius, 1);// - temp fra infrarød
  //display.print("10*");
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(63,23);
  display.print("o");
  display.display();
}

void luftTemp1()
{
  display.clearDisplay();
  float tempNTC = temp.getTemp();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(15,5);
  display.print("Luft temp:");
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(15,25);
  display.print(tempNTC, 1);
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(63,23);
  display.print("o");
  display.display();

}

void distance1()
{
  display.clearDisplay();

  float radius = 0.35; //meter. Dette skal brugeren selv skrive ind fra skaermen.
  float hjulomkreds =  3.14 * (radius*2);


  reedVal = digitalRead(reed);//get val of A0



  if(reedVal == 1 && counter == 1)
  {
    counter = 0;

    start = millis();

  }
  if(reedVal == 0 && counter == 0)
  {

    counter = 2;
  }


  if(reedVal == 1 && counter == 2)
  {
    finished = millis();
    elapsed = (finished - start);
    array[1] = elapsed;
    tid = array[1];

    counter = 0;
    start = millis();
    distance = distance + hjulomkreds;
  }
  delay(200);

  //float hastighed = ((hjulomkreds * 3600)/tid); //  Km/t
  float hastighed =   ((hjulomkreds/tid)*3600);




  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(15,5);
  display.print("Distance:");
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(20,25);
  display.print(distance/1000); // - distance fra sensor
  display.display();
  //display.print("10 km");
}


void fart1()
{
  display.clearDisplay();

  float radius = 0.35; //meter. Dette skal brugeren selv skrive ind fra skaermen.
  float hjulomkreds = 2 * 3.14 * radius*radius;


  reedVal = digitalRead(reed);//get val of A0



  if(reedVal == 1 && counter == 1)
  {
    counter = 0;

    start = millis();

  }
  if(reedVal == 0 && counter == 0)
  {

    counter = 2;
  }


  if(reedVal == 1 && counter == 2)
  {
    finished = millis();
    elapsed = (finished - start);
    array[1] = elapsed;
    tid = array[1];

    counter = 0;
    start = millis();
    distance = distance + 0.35;
  }
  delay(200);


  float hastighed =   ((hjulomkreds/tid)*3600);


  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(15,5);
  display.print("Hastighed:");
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(1,25);
  display.print(hastighed, 1); // - farten fra sensor
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK);
  display.setCursor(53,32);
  display.print("km/t");
  display.display();
  //display.print("25 km/t");
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////










//////////////////////////////////    START SKÆRM    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void skaermSetup1()
{
  ur();
  luftTemp();
  vejTemp();
  fart();
  distance2();
  display.display();
  display.clearDisplay(); 
}  
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////










////////////////////////////////////     SETUP AF SKÆRM     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void setup()  
{
  i2c_init(); //Initialise the i2c bus
  PORTC = (1 << PORTC4) | (1 << PORTC5);//enable pullups
  pinMode(25, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(22, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(24, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(26, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  display.begin();
  display.setContrast(50);
  display.setRotation(2);
  display.display(); // show splashscreen
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();   // clears the screen and buffer
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////











////////////////////////////////////BUZZER//////////////////////////////////
void ylyd()
{
  tone(8, NOTE_C4, 300);
  delay(500);
  tone(8, NOTE_C4, 300);
  delay(1000);
  countLyd=0;
}


void rlyd()
{
  tone(8, NOTE_C4, 300);
  delay(500);
  tone(8, NOTE_C4, 300);
  delay(500);
  tone(8, NOTE_C4, 300);
  delay(500);
  tone(8, NOTE_C4, 300);
  delay(500);
  tone(8, NOTE_C4, 300);
  delay(1000);
  countLyd=1;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////











void loop() 
{
  float tempNTC = temp.getTemp();

  int dev = 0x5A<<1;
  int data_low = 0;
  int data_high = 0;
  int pec = 0;

  i2c_start_wait(dev+I2C_WRITE);
  i2c_write(0x07);

  // read
  i2c_rep_start(dev+I2C_READ);
  data_low = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
  data_high = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
  pec = i2c_readNak();
  i2c_stop();

  //This converts high and low bytes together and processes temperature, MSB is a error bit and is ignored for temps
  double tempFactor = 0.02; // 0.02 degrees per LSB (measurement resolution of the MLX90614)
  double tempData = 0x0000; // zero out the data
  int frac; // data past the decimal point

  // This masks off the error bit of the high byte, then moves it left 8 bits and adds the low byte.
  tempData = (double)(((data_high & 0x007F) << 8) + data_low);
  tempData = (tempData * tempFactor)-0.01;

  float celcius = tempData - 273.15;
  float fahrenheit = (celcius*1.8) + 32;










///////////////////////////////////////     DET MED KNAPPER     ///////////////////////////////////////////////

  int knapVal = digitalRead(12);

  if (knapVal == LOW & buttonState ==1)
  {
    count = count+1;
    buttonState = 2; 
  }

  if (knapVal == HIGH & buttonState ==2)
  {
    buttonState =1; 
  }

  if(count==0)
  {
    skaermSetup1();

  }
  if(count==1){
    display.clearDisplay();
    ur1();
    display.display();
  }

  if(count==2){
    display.clearDisplay();
    vejTemp1();
    display.display();
  }

  if(count==3){
    display.clearDisplay();
    luftTemp1();
    display.display();
  }

  if(count==4){
    display.clearDisplay();
    fart1();
    display.display();
  }

  if(count==5){
    display.clearDisplay();
    distance1();
    display.display();
  }

  if(count==6)
  {
    count=0; 
  }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////











//////////////////////////////////    DET MED LYS    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if(tempNTC < 26 || celcius < 26) // ændres til 0 og 0
  {
    lysR();

    if (countLyd==0)
    {
      rlyd();
    }
  }


  else if(tempNTC > 30 && celcius < 30)
  {
    lysY();
    if (countLyd==1 || countLyd==2)
    {
      ylyd();
    }
  }

  else if(tempNTC < 30 && celcius > 30)
  {
    lysY();
    if (countLyd==1 || countLyd==2)
    {
      ylyd();
    }
  }

  else if(tempNTC < 30 && celcius < 30 && celcius > 26 && tempNTC > 26) // ændres til 2 og 2 og 0 og 0
  {
    lysY();
    if ((countLyd==1 || countLyd==2))
    { 
      ylyd();
    }
  }

  else if(tempNTC > 30 && celcius > 30) // ændres til 2 og 2
  {
    lysG();
    countLyd=2;
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}// LOOP END
```

Comment: 1. I believe your complier has given you some more information. Show them also. 2. always maintain a space between the operands and the operator while using binary or ternary ones, gives better readability.

Comment: your i++ in while loop will never be called.

Comment: I've added all the error messages, also Ali786 could you explain why it won't? It has worked fine in the functional code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is on this line, but it's hard to know because you didn't say which line the compiler gives you error on:

```
while (i<STR)
```

This is because you do:

```
#define STR 100;
```

The pre-processor will change that to:

```
while (i<100;)
```

which is not a valid expression in C.

Comment: and how is that? i think there is no `;` there (in _functional_ code).

Comment: @NatashaDutta There is. In the second code that's marked as "Disfunctional code;", under the comment that says "//////////////////GLOBALE DATAVÆRDIER/////////////////////"

Comment: Sorry for my bad input :) but it is based on the while function as you pointed out yes (Which is the same function I showed in its functional state). I'll try without the defined STR.

**Answer:** Seems to go through verify, still confused as to -why- that made it disfunctional when that worked in the other code.

Comment: @jonasnielsen In the other code you didn't have a semi-colon there. Which made the while loop into `while (i<100)`, which is correct. `while (i<100;)` is not valid C.

Comment: @Art same. i was following that _functional_ code, too. :-) will update my answer also.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i'm missing something [as you've not put complete code], but you have defined something called

```
float mindst_luft;
```

and you're using

```
mindstLuft=1000;
```

In the *Functional* code you've shown, `mindstLuft` is not defined anywhere.

Also, your `while()` loop is useless, because, on you're calling `return` unconditionally.

---

EDIT:

Ok then, what is exactly `A0` ? and `A1`, `A2`...? if you want to represent some `hex` value, you've got to use like `0xA0`.

---

EDIT:

Ok, by avoiding the confusion of *functional* and *disfunctional* code, the problem is with the MACRO definition. Considering the MACRO processing as a *word-by-word* replacement,

```
#define STR 100;
               ^
               |
```

will make your while loop look like

```
while(i < 100;)
```

which is a wrong syntax.

get rid of the `;` in `#define`

Comment: I noticed this it was from when i tried testing a bit, the error was there before. So edited to fit when everything is useing mindstLuft rather than mindst_luft.

Comment: I'll try answer my best (working in a project group of 6). All A# are the analog ports of the arduino and has the following assignments at the moment;

A0 = NTC (for measuring the air temperature)

A1 = empty atm

A2 = empty atm

Comment: @jonasnielsen i did not understand, could you please show the exact code? also, the signature of `analogRead()` function, please

Comment: for the arduino we have analog ports which receive input from various sensors, the A0 port is for a NTC sensor which can be used to measure the temperature on it, which, means it can measure the air-temperature around it. The ports A2 and A3 are currently empty as they are not being used, but are supposed to be soon. AnalogRead() pretty much just reads the current going through it at the time and saves it in a data-type.

Comment: @jonasnielsen ok. Hope your problem is solved now. :-)